# Downloadhelper firefox Failed Conv,FFpmeg PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I've tried to download videos from youtube and convert them using Downloadhelper but the conversion fails. I opened FFpmeg on terminal and get the message "*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead." I tried this and use avconv but the conversion still fails. I have VLC installed also, someone said it might help... But it didn't =[

Answer (score 0):

You can try a web-based tool for downloading youtube videos to your computer. Most sites will give you many options for which type and size the video will be. One site that has worked well for me is www.keepvid.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some videos and I have not yet completely solved the conversion problem. But I switched the conversion settings to use Avconv and installed the following packages:

> libavcodec53, libavcodec-dev, libavcodec-extra-53, libav-tools, libavformat53, libavformat-extra-53, & libavformat-dev.

Now the conversion worked!

What i still don't know is where the 'command files' of Video Download Helper are saved to tweak the conversion preferences to my needs and wishes...

Answer (score 0):

I download a lot too, if you're using Firefox or Google Chrome my advice `SaveFrom.net helper` for me it's ultimate solution it downloads from more than 40 websites including audio and video 360/480/720/1080p resolution. You can find it in Firefox add-ons or Google WebStore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great browser script, which works with [GreaseMonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/).

It is called **YouTube Links.**
It is available [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5566-youtube-links) ([archived](http://archive.li/APGlv#7%25)).
And here is the [source code](http://web.archive.org/web/20190216031759/https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5566-youtube-links/code/YouTube%20Links.user.js).

I have chosen it, because it works without derouting to an external downloading webapp.

[image]